# Flowchart convert into java program input methodology

Tags: java, logic, flowchart

Can somebody help me about this flow chart in my java program, because I am  new to java. So far I know how to code, but when it comes to flowchart I feel dumb.

Here is what I understand so far: First I'll get input from user then match it with `cnt=1` but afterwards again `cnt<=line` then again `cnt2=1`.

```
cnt1 means count 1
cnt2 means count 2
input line is input number only.
```

[image: flowchart]

Comment: kindly check the image FLOWCHART TO JAVA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please explain your question more clearly:

What do you mean here cnt<=line?

What is 'line' here?

May be below program will help, is this what you are expecting:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class SchoolHomework {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Enter number only:");
            int line = sc.nextInt();
            int cnt = 1;
            int cnt2 = 0;
            while (cnt <= line) {
                cnt2 = 1;
                while (cnt2 <= line) {
                    if (cnt2 <= line) {
                        System.out.println("*");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("#");
                    }
                    cnt2++;
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
                cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i added a image